# Set fullscreen to vimeo player using Blazor hosted

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, vimeo-player

I have succesfully embed a vimeo player in my Blazor app. Now my client requested to display the fullscreen control. According to the documentation it should go like this:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

and indeed, if I put it like this it certainly displays the fullsreen control. The problem is that I need that the video src to be dynamic, thus, my code is like this:

```
        <iframe src="@videoSrc" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

And then, the fullscreen control won't display anymore. Trying to dig into the issue, inspecting the html that gets created, the difference is that in the latter, the player is created with a `no-fullscreen-support`.
I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: please provide your code ? how do you set @videoSrc ?  Do you call StateHasChanged afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is how I solved my problem. Per the docs [here](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#pre-existing-player) I was using the player like this:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on('play', function() {
        console.log('played the video!');
    });

    player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('title:', title);
    });
</script>
```

But it looks like for some reason Blazor wraps the iFrame in such a way that makes the Vimeo player not to be able to go fullscreen.

I changed to this, per the docs [here](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#create-with-a-video-id-or-url). In this case, the `options.id` is the videoSrc/videoUrl

```
<div id="made-in-ny"></div>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
    var options = {
        id: 59777392,
        width: 640,
        loop: true
    };

    var player = new Vimeo.Player('made-in-ny', options);

    player.setVolume(0);

    player.on('play', function() {
        console.log('played the video!');
    });
</script>
```